# distinct not working in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, distinct

i have two tables in my db .. one is **Messages** and the other is **Contacts**... both tables contain the mobile_number field.. in Contacts table there is no duplicate numbers ... but in Messages tables there are several duplicate numbers in mobileNo field...what i am doing is write now i am selecting the distinct mobile numbers from the **Messages** tables and then i am comparring the distinct numbers from the contacts table ... so if the messages_mobileNo is found on the contacts table then give me the contact name against the number otherwise messages_mobileNo ... so the problem is distinct not working .. i am not able to get the distinct numbers from the Messages table ... it is showing me the duplicate numbers

here is my query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Message.mobileNo,
            Contact.mobileNo,
            Contact.workNo,
            Contact.homeNo,
            Contact.other,
            Contact.name,

            Message.body,
            Message.idTextMessage
FROM cakephp_db.textmessage AS Message
LEFT JOIN cakephp_db.contacts AS Contact ON (Message.user_id = Contact.user_id
                                         AND ((Message.mobileNo = Contact.mobileNo)
                                              OR (Message.mobileNo = Contact.workNo)
                                              OR (Message.mobileNo = Contact.homeNo)
                                              OR (Message.mobileNo = Contact.other)))
 WHERE Message.User_id = 23
 ORDER BY Message.idTextMessage DESC LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your trying to get the last 6 messages of a person if I'm right?

```
 SELECT Message.mobileNo,
            Contact.mobileNo,
            Contact.workNo,
            Contact.homeNo,
            Contact.other,
            Contact.name,

            Message.body,
            Message.idTextMessage
FROM cakephp_db.textmessage AS Message
LEFT JOIN cakephp_db.contacts AS Contact ON Message.user_id = Contact.user_id
                                         AND Message.mobileNo IN (Contact.mobileNo, Contact.workNo, Contact.homeNo, Contact.other)
 WHERE Message.User_id = 23
GROUP BY Message.mobileNo
 ORDER BY Message.idTextMessage DESC LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `GROUP BY Message.mobileNo` before your `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL SELECT DISTINCT with an ORDER BY added to it, you will have to create a temporary table where it can store its results. Here is a link offering more help:

[MySQL DISTINCT Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)